# Why is the firebase cloud function not triggering when document is created at responses

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

```
exports.createHook = functions.database.ref('/Responses/{ResponsesId}').onCreate((snap, context) => {
    console.log('triggered')
    var response = snap.val
    console.log(response.text);
});
```

I've written to firestore and its not triggering, what am I missing?

[Here is a picture of my functions panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RoPHI.png) its clearly deploying to the cloud

[Here is a picture of the logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HFDrd.png) its only logging when the function is built so it isn't executing.

Comment: How are you calling it? Also, snap.val is missing the call: snap.val()

Comment: By how are you calling it I mean - are you creating a new entry at `/Responses/newEntryId`?

Comment: I'm not calling it, its running in firebase cloud functions .onCreate should call every time there is a write to the reference

Comment: Have you deployed it to firebase?

Comment: Also, iirc, you need to add a valid credit card to be able to use the cloud functions.

Comment: HTTP functions are running however this is the first time I've ever used the onCreate trigger

Comment: Go to firebase console then click on functions and see if you see the function listed on there should be called createHook, also, there is a logs tab in the functions, do you see any errors there?

Comment: When you write a function for firebase, it has to be deployed, have you done that?

Answer (score 2):

> I have written to **firestore** and it is not triggering

You may have written to Firestore, but your code is written as a Firebase [Realtime Database trigger](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events) (it uses `functions.database`).  You need to use [Firestore triggers](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events) to respond to events in Firestore (alternatively, you need to write your updates into a Realtime Database, not Firestore).

It is very easy to get these confused (they're named so similarly!) but they are not the same and need to be coded differently.

For example, the prototype for a Firestore `onCreate` trigger should look something like:

```js
exports.createHook = functions.firestore
    .document('Responses/{ResponsesId}')
    .onCreate((change, context) => { .... }
```

Also in the comment thread I note that you said "onCreate should call every time there is a write to the reference".  This is not correct.  `onCreate` should only be called when the document is first written to.